# TemplateView mysteriously unavailable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two hosts, on both of which I've installed django 1.3.1, I see different behavior:

Host 1:

```
jeff@nantes:purple $ python --version
Python 2.6.5
jeff@nantes:purple $ python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.views.generic import TemplateView
>>>
```

On host 2:

```
jeff@s8:~/purpledom$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
jeff@s8:~/purpledom$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.10 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]: from django.views.generic import TemplateView
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/jeff/purpledom/<ipython console> in <module>()

ImportError: cannot import name TemplateView

In [2]:
```

It looks like django/views/generic/base.py defines TemplateView the same way in each.  The minor version change in python seems like a red herring (but I can't prove it).

Any suggestions?

And of course the one with the error is my production host. :(

Comment: What's on `sys.path`? What does `import django.views.generic` yield (module objects have filename attached)?

Comment: do you have more than one version of django installed? i ran into something similar when it was referencing an old version of django vs 1.3.x

Comment: sys.path isn't too exciting: just my project directory, the innocuous and non-django ~/.ipython, and a bunch of system stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, running different versions of Python has nothing to do with this, especially when it's just the difference of a security/bug-fix release.

My best guess is that even though you may have Django 1.3 installed on both, the production server is still using a lesser version. Try running `django-admin.py --version` and see what comes up. I bet it's not going to be 1.3. Remove any older Django eggs or folders in your Python path and try again.

Comment: Thanks!  You're absolutely right!  1.3.1 (working host) vs 1.2.3 (non-working host).

Sorry to be a bit slow, but how do I find older eggs or folders?  I know what I installed, and then there's the (non-django) system python installation, hopefully not relevant.

Comment: Nothing called django here:
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"

Comment: @jma in the Python shell, do `import django; django.__file__`, which should show you the path to the django directory.

Comment: Aha!  So it's going to /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/__init__.pyc.

Comment: Is there a way around that without talking to sysadmins?

Comment: If you can customize your PYTHONPATH, you should be able to at least make your copy of Django load first or bypass the defaults completely. It might be worth looking into virtualenv, as well. If you convert your site to run out of a virtualenv instance, then you can control every package explicitly, assuming you can get by with using it on your server.

Comment: Yup, PYTHONPATH does the trick for my standalone example.  I'll have a look at virtualenv, thanks!